# Use of phrase before adjectives

Tags: adjectives

In sentence below should i use '' ten dollars lower '' before the word '' price'' or after . Or both gives same meaning.

> He offered me ten dollars lower price than you
>
> He offered me price ten dollars lower than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make both work, but you are missing articles and verbs.

If you simplify the sentence to the bare minimum of "He offered me" then to answer the question "what did he offer?" you would say "a price" so "He offered me a price."

Then we want to describe the price, we can say either "a price ten dollars lower" or "ten dollar lower price." Notice dollar is not plural in the second phrase ...

Finally, we need to fix up the "than you." That phrase is incomplete because the price isn't comparable to "you," it is comparable to "your price" or "your offer" so you would say something like "than your price," "than yours," or "than you did."

> He offered me **a** ten dollar lower price than you **did**.

or

> He offered me **a** price ten dollars lower than you**rs**.